# If a sequence has a convergent sub-sequence, then the sequence converges(fake proof)

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, fake-proofs

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $x_n$ be a sequence such that it has a convergent sub-sequence $x_{n_k} \to x $, then $x_n \to  x$

This is false, for example, the sequence $(-1)^n$ has a convergent sub-sequence but it does not converge.

Here's a proof of the above statement, I can't figure out what  the flaw is.

Proof:

Suppose that $x_n$ does not converge to $x$, so there exists an $\epsilon$ such that for all $N$ we have $$n \geq N  \rightarrow d(x_n, x) \geq \epsilon$$ on the other hand there is an $N_\epsilon$ such that $$n_k\geq N_\epsilon \rightarrow d(x_{n_k},x) < \epsilon$$ since $x_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of $x_n$, its members are also members of the main sequence, therefore there are members of $x_n$ such that $d(x_n,x) < \epsilon$ which is a contradiction.

What is wrong with this proof?

Comment: The problem is in the very first line. $d(x_n,x) < \epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$ being false does not in any way mean $d(x_n,x) \ge \epsilon$ for *all* $n\ge N$.  It just means there is at least one $n\ge N$ where $d(x_n,x)\ge \epsilon$.

Comment: This equivalent to the following prove.  If some horse are brown than all horses are brown.  Suppose all horses are not brown; then there is some other color that all horses are.  Call it "grue".  But some horse are brown and therefore those are not grue.  That's a contradiction.  So all horse are brown.

Comment: I like that analogy, so I couldn't figure out what the flaw was because I failed to notice that the negation of convergence was wrong! How silly

Comment: When, as in this question, you have a fake proof and a specific counterexample, an effective way to find the flaw in the proof is to apply it to your counterexample. In this case, that would mean writing the proof with every $x_n$ replaced with $(-1)^n$. Then, if necessary, check line by line to see where the proof for this specific example goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contrapositive is wrong. To say $x_n \not\rightarrow x$ is to say

\begin{equation}
\exists\epsilon>0 \text{ s.t. } \forall N \in \mathbb{N} \: \: \exists n \geq N \text{ s.t. } d(x_n,x) \geq \epsilon
\end{equation}

And not

\begin{equation}
\exists\epsilon>0 \text{ s.t. } \forall N \in \mathbb{N} \: \: \forall n \geq N \text{ s.t. } d(x_n,x) \geq \epsilon
\end{equation}

The first allows the existence of the subsequence because not all $n$ are obligated to satisfy $d(x_{n_k},x) \geq \epsilon $.